# Having trouble creating a docx js file, won't open with MS word

Tags: typescript, docx

I'm creating a resume template with the docx js library and i worked on getting the it to generate the bullet points and multiple jobs using some fuction i created to map through. I got it to work... sort of it creates it but the docx file wont open with ms word but when i open it with another application it shows all the info was generated correctly. what am I doing wrong?

```
    const testData1 = new resumeData(
  new UserProfile("John", "Doe", "email@email.com, ", "(213)555-4589"),
  [
    new WorkHistory(
      "Front end engineer",
      "Job 1",
      new Date("2020-01-01"),
      [
        "job 1 duty 1",
        "job 2 duty 2",
        "job 3 duty 3",
      ],
      new Date("2019-01-01")
    ),
    new WorkHistory(
      "Software Engineer",
      "Job 2",
      new Date("Present"),
      [
        "job 2 duty 1",
        "job 2 duty 2",
        "job 2 duty 3",
      ],
      new Date("2021-01-01")
    ),
  ],
  [
    new Education(
      "Bachelor of Science",
      "Computer Science",
      "University of California, Los Angeles",
      3.5,
      new Date("2021-06-01")
    ),
  ],
  [
    new Certificate(
      "AWS Certified Cloud Practitioner",
      "Amazon",
      new Date("2021-01-01")
    ),
  ],
  [new Award("Employee of the Month", "Google", new Date("2020-01-01"))]
);

const createDutiesList = (duties: WorkHistory["duties"]) => {
  return duties.map(
    (duty) =>
      new Paragraph({
        children: [
          new TextRun({
            text: duty,
          })
        ],
        bullet: {
          level: 0,
        }
      })
  );
};

const createJobHistory = (workHistory: WorkHistory[]) => {
  return workHistory.map(
    (job) =>
      new Paragraph({
        children: [
          new Paragraph({
            children: [new TextRun({ text: job.title })],
          }),
          new Paragraph({
            children: [new TextRun({ text: job.company })],
          }),
          new Paragraph({
            children: [
              new TextRun({
                text: `${job.startDate} - ${
                  job.endDate ? job.endDate : "Present"
                }`,
              }),
            ]
          }),
          ...createDutiesList(job.duties),
        ]
      })
  );
};

// Create a new document with all sections
const doc = new docx.Document({
  sections: [
    {
      properties: {},
      children: [
        new Paragraph({
          children: [
            new TextRun({
              text: `${testData1.UserProfile.firstName} ${testData1.UserProfile.lastName}`,
            }),
          ],
          heading: HeadingLevel.HEADING_2
        }),
        new Paragraph({
          text: `Email: ${testData1.UserProfile.email}             Phone: ${testData1.UserProfile.phoneNumber}`,
          heading: HeadingLevel.HEADING_1
        }),
        new Paragraph(
          "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit."
        ),
        new Paragraph({
          text: "Summary",
          heading: HeadingLevel.HEADING_1,
        }),
        ...createJobHistory(testData1.WorkHistory)
      ]
    }
  ]
});

export default doc;
```

I tried rewriting it because i thought maybe the issue is having a Paragraph inside a Paragraph is something it doesn't like but then that breaks it another way I've been trying to figure this for a bit now with no luck.